# Udp Connection With just knowing Dynamic IP

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, udp

I have WIMAX internet with static IP.

My clients connect to this with static ip and Windows Service App that manages sending and receive text message using a TCP connection.
Now I want to add an option to this app, Online speaking... like Viber

I know that I must use the UDP protocol.

My question is: when client (A) connect to my windows service app i have client (A) IP Address and also other client like (B) too.
Can I make UDP connection with client A and B without my server app and internet after sending client ip address to each other, that forward receiving buffer to each other??

Let me tell more :
client A send request call for client B to my server app
I know ip A and B, now my server app send B ip address to A and A ip address to B, after that client A and B both of them has thair IP, can make connection with them with UDP?

Comment: It's not that you must use UDP, it's just recommended but it does also work on TCP, as long as you have a reliable connection.

Comment: yes of course i can use TCP, but when speed is more important than reliable We should not use TCP.

Comment: Indeed, and your question also interests me, but I don't have the answer :/

Comment: for doing this i think we must define dynamic port forwarding on WIMIX router or ADSL router, or...